# SMB/CIFS server implementation in JAVA

Tags: open-source, samba, sharing

I'm looking for an SMB/CIFS server (The file sharing part) implementation that:

- Is open source
- Runs on Java

Does this exist?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Like you are you wanting a GUI or CLI fine? what OS(es) (Even though Java is cross-platform it is good to specify in case of system library requirements)?

Comment: Are we looking for this for you to include in a project, or as a standalone application? If you're primarily interested in the former, answers would include libraries, if not, they would be software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a Java open source SMB/CIFS implementation, it is called [JLAN](http://www.alfresco.com/news/press-releases/alfresco-makes-leading-java-implementation-jlan-shared-file-drive-interface).

I have used it for 6 years and I am quite happy with it.
It is used in many companies by employees to perform their everyday work, so it is pretty robust.

The source code can be found here:
https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/services/jlan/

License: GNU LGPL v3
Well-maintained.

Comment: The repository has been moved to https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/services/jlan/

Comment: Sadly CIFS/SMB1 is very old and dangerous and SMB3 support is not a plan for Alfresco :( - see https://community.alfresco.com/thread/231880-smb2-smb3-server-support

Comment: Since SMB1 is now disabled in the newer Windows OSs, Alfresco is debating whether to upgrade to SMB3 through a third party or to move to WebDAV instead.
I hope they won't compromise on WebDaV and will continue with SMB support